# TimeSpan Calculation Error

Tags: c#, datetime, numbers, double

I created a small piece of software in c# that calculates overtime in decimal format.  I have designed it so that it always rounds down to the nearest tenth of an hour.  The problem that I am having is that when I try to calculate a time that is exactly 2 hours 12 minutes or 3 hours 12 minutes I get an incorrect result.  The relevant code follows:

```
   DateTime start = new DateTime(
                        dtpDateStart.Value.Year,
                        dtpDateStart.Value.Month,
                        dtpDateStart.Value.Day,
                        dtpTimeStart.Value.Hour,
                        dtpTimeStart.Value.Minute,
                        0);

        DateTime end = new DateTime(
            dtpDateEnd.Value.Year,
            dtpDateEnd.Value.Month,
            dtpDateEnd.Value.Day,
            dtpTimeEnd.Value.Hour,
            dtpTimeEnd.Value.Minute,
            0);

        TimeSpan subtotal = end - start;

        double subtotalRounded = subtotal.TotalHours;
        subtotalRounded = (Math.Floor(subtotalRounded * 10) / 10);
```

`dtpDateStart`, `dtpTimeStart`, `dtpDateEnd` and `dtpTimeEnd` are all date time picker controls in a Win Forms project.

When I debug this code I find that the returned value of `subtotalRounded` is either 2.1999999999999997 or 3.1999999999999997 instead of 2.2 and 3.2. This doesn't seem to happen with values of 4 hours 12 minutes or greater or 1 hour 12 minutes or less.

Anyways, I'm completely stumped why rounding error occurs with only these two values. Does anyone have any suggestions or comments?  Am I using the method incorrectly or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: This seems just like a floating point "error" (quotes intentional). If you don't want rounding issues (especially in the decimal fraction): don't use double - so: work in minutes (or seconds, or whatever precision you want) as an integer, or if you really really want to use a decimal like this: convert from minutes (seconds, whatever) to `decimal`

Answer (score 2):

You use a `double` which is precise on its bit representation, not its decimal representation. Use the `decimal` data type instead. [Microsoft](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187912(v=sql.105).aspx) states this:

> Avoid using float or real columns in WHERE clause search conditions,
>   especially the = and <> operators. It is best to limit float and real
>   columns to > or < comparisons.

Change these two code lines

```
double subtotalRounded = subtotal.TotalHours;
subtotalRounded = (Math.Floor(subtotalRounded * 10) / 10);
```

to this:

```
decimal subtotalRounded = subtotal.TotalHours; // See data type!
subtotalRounded = (Math.Floor(subtotalRounded * 10) / 10);
```

or even shorter this:

```
decimal subtotalRounded = = (Math.Floor(subtotal.TotalHours * 10) / 10);
```

You may need to do proper data type conversion. If so, you can use the helper methods from the `Convert` class.

Comment: It does indeed sound like the age old floating point missconceptions. This video explains it well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZRI1IfStY0 Basically if you need precision, you can not use floats ever.

Answer (score 0):

That is simply the way floating point values work, generally you deal with it when displaying rather than when calculating. That is when you do a string.Format("{0:f2}", value) it will then round to the requested number of digits.

Comment: Partially incorrect. Format will not round. It simply cuts of the leftover digits.  Rounding can result in the value being bigger then the cutoff, so it is a very important disticntion.

Answer (score 0):

Certain numbers can't be represented exactly in a `double`. You should either use `decimal` or (preferably) work in minutes and then divide by 60 using `decimal` on output.

Answer (score 0):

You were all right about the floating point numbers.  I converted everything to decimal and it works now.  I'm sure there's a more elegant way to do this but here is my code:

```
        DateTime start = new DateTime(
                        dtpDateStart.Value.Year,
                        dtpDateStart.Value.Month,
                        dtpDateStart.Value.Day,
                        dtpTimeStart.Value.Hour,
                        dtpTimeStart.Value.Minute,
                        0);

        DateTime end = new DateTime(
            dtpDateEnd.Value.Year,
            dtpDateEnd.Value.Month,
            dtpDateEnd.Value.Day,
            dtpTimeEnd.Value.Hour,
            dtpTimeEnd.Value.Minute,
            0);

        TimeSpan subtotal = end - start;

        decimal decSubtotalMinutes = Convert.ToDecimal(subtotal.TotalMinutes);
        decSubtotalMinutes = decSubtotalMinutes / 60;
        decSubtotalMinutes = (Math.Floor(decSubtotalMinutes * 10) / 10);
```

Using decimal makes the calculations come out correctly.  I didn't know that using double would lead to floating point errors.  Thank you to everyone who helped a new programmer out!